# Automatic superposition of similar objects?

Tags: objects

Is there a way to superpose objects automatically by shape recognition or something like that in a way to compare their shape easily ? Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Selecting objects by mesh similarity isn't a feature that Blender currently offers. Theoretically this could be implemented through an add-on.

In edit mode there are option to select similar areas on the current mesh. This is not shape recognition though.

Comment: Ok, it's not exactly the same your are right. I don't think I can create this kind of add-on for now ahah, thank you for your answer even if there is no solution !